# How do I round Double data type value

Tags: java, android, data-conversion

Bellow is my code

```
          String Send_Amount = SendAmount.getText().toString();
          Double lastSendAmount = Double.parseDouble(Send_Amount);
          Double LastRate = Double.parseDouble(RATE_FOR_ONE_UNIT);
          Double LastReceiveAmount = lastSendAmount * LastRate;
          ReceiveAmount.setText(LastReceiveAmount.toString());
```

How do I round `LastReceiveAmount` to `"x.ab"` or `"x.ab+0.01"(when b>5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there isn't a "nice" way to do it. But there are many workarounds.

DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

String.format:

```
String.format("%.2f", d);
```

Math Workaround:

```
double val = ....;
val = val * 100;
val = Math.round(val);
val = val / 100;
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: LastReceiveAmount=String.format("%.2f",LastReceiveAmount)

Comment: Is it like this?

Answer (score 1):

With

```
String.format("%.2f", d)
```

for 2 decimals

Comment: So LastReceiveAmount=String.format("%.2f",LastReceiveAmount

Comment: Is it like this?

Comment: Worked tnx a lot